# Android pull to refresh listview data duplication while fetching data from localhost php and mysql server

Tags: android, mysql, listview, pull-to-refresh

my php code for fetching data from database.. can anybody tell me how can i load data into my android  pull to refresh listview only new data

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM hotelbook";
 $res = mysql_query($sql);

 $arr = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
       $arr[] = $row;
 }


 die(json_encode($arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use [Recyclerview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Next to that is [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMoctEcSEo8).

As the above **Example link** will describes you all the things step by step.

Comment: i can't  understand video it's in different language  and i have use custom pull to refresh listview and it show same data again and again while i refresh listview